# fixed navigation bar left with items take equal height vertically aligned

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-float, vertical-alignment

I am creating a simple left floated fixed vertical navigation bar which takes 100% of viewport height and each list item should take equal height. I have managed to do all this but can't get the list items text to vertically align in the center according to the individual item's height. Please see my code below.[image]

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  color: ghostwhite;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  width: 10%;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.main-content {
  width: 90%;
  background: #25b99a;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header, .main-content {
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
}


header nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
header nav ul li, header nav ul li a {
  height: 33.33vh;
  display: block;
  color: ghostwhite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    
    
    <div class="main-content">
      <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus obcaecati cum rerum vel nesciunt ratione est! At rem totam sed maxime reprehenderit nihil quam mollitia dicta est laborum, possimus vero aspernatur commodi cum quia corporis earum porro, temporibus provident, veritatis.</p>
    </div>
    
    
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `<span>` in the nav helps a bit: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/owxLZr

Comment: Thanks, really helped. I also tried line-height: set the the height to height of each li and seems to work. Do you think this is a right approach to the problem?

Comment: No problem! I would not use the line-height for this. Because if you ever end up having a 2 line long `<li>` in your navigation, it would look like 2 separate elements. Using `<span>` here, allow you to have a reliable code that is more responsive and content-based. You could also use the flexbox grid for that (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)